Extract text from htm in python where the tags aren't consistent
I need to extract a section of the SEC filings. Unfortunately these are filed differently by different companies so the source code is different on every page and it doens't look like I can pull outdata by tag. I was trying the code below but I can't get it to work. Does anyone know how I can get it to find the text correctly so I can return the right string please? At the moment it doesn't find the strings and so returns everything or nothing depending on the URL.
I think the problem might be the spaces in the formatting which is preventing it finding the keywords in the code and bringing back the right part. Different URLs have different formating return different start and end values e.g. https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0000731766/000073176624000085/unh-20240221.htm
It also might not be followed by Item 9.01. So, if anyone knows how to extract the section following Item 7.01 only that would be incredibly helpful.
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312524011295/d708866d8k.htm"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'email@gmail.com'}

request2 = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

response2 = urllib.request.urlopen(request2)

html2 = response2.read()

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, features="html.parser")

text2 = soup2.get_text()

start_index = text2.find("Item 7.01")

end_index = text2.find("Item 9.01")

result_string = text2[start_index:end_index]

print(text2)
print(start_index)
print(end_index)
print(result_string)

I've tried changing the URL to string, 'string', "string" in case that helps, but it didn't. I'm not sure what else to try.

I see no Item 7.01 or Item 9.01 in the text in URL you provided.

Please inspect the HTML that you are receiving from that website, and find the text: "Your Request Originates from an Undeclared Automated Tool"  After that read the rest of the text.....

I can't see the text "Your Request Originates from an Undeclared Automated Tool" when I run it. It needs an email in the header to check that it isn't from a bot, maybe it doesn't like the one I put in?

item 7.01 and 9.01 are in there, they are within the large block of text starting "NASDAQ Indicate by check mark.." in the text2 string. For some URLS they are pulled out correctly, and some like this they aren't found even though I can see they are there. I tried looking at the soup vairable instead but the tags were different for each html page so I couldn't see a way to extract the items that way.

The issue seems to be the non-breaking space and one approach could be to replace it, so it fits your selection / string you like to find:
html2.replace(r'&#160;', " ")

To extract the only the section/content taht follows, check its next_siblings and break by a condition in that specific case if next Item starts:
for e in soup.find(string=re.compile("Item 7.01.")).parent.next_siblings:
    if e.get_text(strip=True).startswith('Item'):
        break
    else:
        print(e.get_text(strip=True))

Example
Used requests here but result is the same.
import requests, re

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312524011295/d708866d8k.htm"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'some-agent'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text.replace(r'&#160;', " "))

for e in soup.find(string=re.compile("Item 7.01.")).parent.next_siblings:
    if e.get_text(strip=True).startswith('Item'):
        break
    else:
        print(e.get_text(strip=True))

Output
On January 19, 2024, the Company posted a blog regarding the incident. A copy of the blog is furnished as Exhibit 99.1 to this report.
In accordance with General Instruction B.2of Form 8-K, the informationin this Item 7.01 and Exhibit 99.1, shall not be deemed to be “filed” for purposes of Section 18 of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934, as amended (the “Exchange Act”), or otherwise subject to the liability of that section, and shall not be incorporated by reference into any registration statement or other document filed under the Securities Act of 1933, as amended, or the Exchange Act, except as shall be expressly set forth by specific reference in such filing.


Thanks @HedgeHog this works perfectly for one URL but not the other. I think what I want may not be possible due to the different formats, whenever I think I have an answer I try a different URL and it doesn't work. I might just have to leave the text extraction part out.

The other url as mentioned do not contain the value 7.01 So it will not give a result. As long as the question not cover all relevant cases or is not that focused it is hard to complete answer
